# Unable to create call adapter for class example.Simple

Tags: java, rest, retrofit, simple-framework

I am using retrofit 2.0.0-beta1 with SimpleXml. I want the retrieve a Simple (XML) resource from a REST service.
Marshalling/Unmarshalling the Simple object with SimpleXML works fine.

When using this code (converted form pre 2.0.0 code):

```
final Retrofit rest = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl(endpoint)
    .build();
SimpleService service = rest.create(SimpleService.class);
LOG.info(service.getSimple("572642"));
```

Service:

```
public interface SimpleService {

    @GET("/simple/{id}")
    Simple getSimple(@Path("id") String id);

}
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for class example.Simple
    for method SimpleService.getSimple
    at retrofit.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:201)
    at retrofit.MethodHandler.createCallAdapter(MethodHandler.java:51)
    at retrofit.MethodHandler.create(MethodHandler.java:30)
    at retrofit.Retrofit.loadMethodHandler(Retrofit.java:138)
    at retrofit.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:127)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getSimple(Unknown Source)
```

What am i missing? I know that wrapping the return type by a `Call` works. But I want the service to return business objects as type (and working in sync mode).

**UPDATE**

After added the extra dependancies and `.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())` as suggested by different answers, I still get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for class simple.Simple. Tried:
 * retrofit.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory
 * retrofit.DefaultCallAdapter$1
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617770/how-to-get-response-as-string-using-retrofit-without-using-gson-or-any-other-lib

Comment: For those who are using Coroutine check @chatlanin answer

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Short answer: return [`Call<Simple>`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/2.0.0-beta2/retrofit/Call.html) in your service interface.

It looks like Retrofit 2.0 is trying to find a way of creating the proxy object for your service interface. It expects you to write this:

```
public interface SimpleService {
    @GET("/simple/{id}")
    Call<Simple> getSimple(@Path("id") String id);
}
```

However, it still wants to play nice and be flexible when you don't want to return a `Call`. To support this, it has the concept of a [`CallAdapter`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/2.0.0-beta2/retrofit/CallAdapter.html), which is supposed to know how to adapt a `Call<Simple>` into a `Simple`.

The use of `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory` is only useful if you are trying to return `rx.Observable<Simple>`.

The simplest solution is to return a `Call` as Retrofit expects. You could also write a [`CallAdapter.Factory`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/2.0.0-beta2/retrofit/CallAdapter.Factory.html) if you really need it.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed the right answer :(. I know from the start that `Call<Simple>` is the way it works. However, as stated in my question my preference is to just return `Simple` (as was the case in the earlier version). My conclusion is: not possible without extra code.

Comment: The link you've provided for `Call<Simple>`  is broken. What package does `Simple` belong to?

Comment: Thanks for the note @shyam. I've updated the links. `Simple` is the class mentioned in the OP's question. The link is to `Call<T>`.

Answer (score 506):

In case of **Kotlin** and **coroutines** this situation happened when I forgot to mark api service function as `suspend` when I call this function from `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{}`:

**Usage:**

```
    val apiService = RetrofitFactory.makeRetrofitService()

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

        val response = apiService.myGetRequest()

        // process response...

    }
```

**ApiService.kt**

```
interface ApiService {

       @GET("/my-get-request")
       suspend fun myGetRequest(): Response<String>
}
```

Comment: putting suspend works..but how? 
can you please explain how did it work

Comment: I was annoyed that all I see is RxJava related answer here and there, but the OP's actual code sample does not even use RxJava. This is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: In my case this error was because i forgot in service mark func us suspend. Thanx for answer. :)

Comment: Should be the accepted answer for kotlin coroutines users

Comment: Thank you, spent 2 hours on this cause I forgot to add it hahahah

Answer (score 57):

add dependencies:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'
```

create your adapter this way:

```
Retrofit rest = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(endpoint)
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
    .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

`addCallAdapterFactory ()` and `addConverterFactory ()` both need to be called.

Service:

```
public interface SimpleService {

    @GET("/simple/{id}")
    Call<Simple> getSimple(@Path("id") String id);

}
```

Modify `Simple` to `Call<Simple>`.

Comment: I know that changing Simple to Call<Simple> does the trick. However, I do not want to introduce type `Call` to the service interface

Comment: You can also use `CompletableFuture` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269064/unable-to-create-call-adapter-for-class-example-simple/55652910#55652910

Answer (score 47):

I used Coroutines with **CoroutineCallAdapterFactory**, but accidentally forgot to make the function **`suspend`**. Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Same for me ) Good catch!

Answer (score 39):

With the new Retrofit(2.+) you need to add addCallAdapterFactory which can be a normal one or a RxJavaCallAdapterFactory(for Observables). I think you can add more than both too. It automatically checks which one to use. See a working example below. You can also check [this link](https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/simple-http-with-retrofit-2-droidcon-nyc-2015) for more details.

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ApiConfig.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build()
```

Comment: Great link! Will check later.

Comment: In the documentation there is still RestAdapter and there is no example how to make most simple request with Retrofit 2.0. I get error Could not resolve RxJavaCallAdapterFactory. Spent few hours to make most simple android http request. It seems it is no so simple as they advertise. Maybe they should document a bit more.

Comment: Use Retrofit instead of RestAdapter if you are using Retrofit 2.0.

Comment: @rmuller Please mark the answer accepted if you find it working as that will help other too..

Comment: @Vlado Are you using all the needed gradle dependencies? Make sure you add compile "com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta1" if you want to use rx related adapters. See the link mentioned in answer above.

Comment: Oh, I didn't installed that dependency.I installed version 1.9 which is documented a bit.more.

Comment: Checked it out. Your code does not work for my example code. My conclusion is that I need a Custom CallAdapter for this use case. Also note that RxJavaCallAdapterFactory needs a extra dependency. Correct?

Comment: RxJavaCallAdapterFactory requires the adapter-rxjava artifact from the same repo. 

```compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta1'```

Comment: This still does not resolve my issue, see updated question

Comment: for retrofit2, ensure you use the correct dependencies `com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0` and  `com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0`

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0

Comment: You don't need any other adapter if you're using `CompletableFuture` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269064/unable-to-create-call-adapter-for-class-example-simple/55652910#55652910

Answer (score 19):

If you want use `retrofit2` and you don't want always return `retrofit2.Call<T>`, you have to create your own `CallAdapter.Factory` which return simple type as you expected. The simple code can look like this:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.CallAdapter;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class SynchronousCallAdapterFactory extends CallAdapter.Factory {
    public static CallAdapter.Factory create() {
        return new SynchronousCallAdapterFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public CallAdapter<Object, Object> get(final Type returnType, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        // if returnType is retrofit2.Call, do nothing
        if (returnType.toString().contains("retrofit2.Call")) {
            return null;
        }

        return new CallAdapter<Object, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Type responseType() {
                return returnType;
            }

            @Override
            public Object adapt(Call<Object> call) {
                try {
                    return call.execute().body();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e); // do something better
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then simple register the `SynchronousCallAdapterFactory` in Retrofit should solved your problem.

```
Retrofit rest = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(endpoint)
        .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(SynchronousCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

After that you can return simple type without `retrofit2.Call`.

```
public interface SimpleService {
    @GET("/simple/{id}")
    Simple getSimple(@Path("id") String id);
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Do you know if there is a way to create an async call adapter? so I can call a service like that: service.getSimple("id",new Adapter(){   onFail(){} onSuccess(){} } instead of using the enqueue() and the callback?

Comment: "implements CallAdapter.Factory"
This is a class not an interface?

Comment: @ozmank In version `2.0.0-beta3` it was an interface, now in version `2.1.0` it is a class. I edited my code, to be more actual. Thanks.

Comment: @MateuszKorwel It always get throw new RuntimeException(e)! I wanna return String instead of Simple.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde It should work. Maybe you rest service dont work? What exception you get when you call `call.execute().body()`?

Comment: Thank you posting this. I have created a library around this handling `Simple getSimple()` and `Response<Simple> getSimple()` requests: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/retrofit2-synchronous-adapter.

Comment: The code in this answer does not throw an HttpException on a response error.   I switched to using the solution from @JaredBurrows.

Answer (score 15):

For this case :

```
val apiService = RetrofitFactory.makeRetrofitService()

CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

    val response = apiService.myGetRequest()

    // process response...

}

interface ApiService {

   @GET("/my-get-request")
   suspend fun myGetRequest(): Response<String>
}
```

All methods used within  `suspend` functions must be marked as `suspend` because of it's manageability by the Corountine. Check more info [here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines).

So if you dont mark your API service function as `suspend` when you call it inside a CoroutineScope or any `suspend` marked method, android app crashes and throws the `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for class example.class` error.

Answer (score 13):

Add the following dependencies for retrofit 2

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
```

for GSON

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

for observables

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
```

In your case for XML , you would have to include the following dependencies

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.1.0'
```

Update the service call as below

```
final Retrofit rest = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
    .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl(endpoint)
    .build();
SimpleService service = rest.create(SimpleService.class);
```

Comment: This is the same as my setup.

Comment: also be sure to add this line when creating adapter:    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0

Comment: @ozmank its retrofit2 , I have updated my answer too. Please try it out

Answer (score 12):

IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for class java.lang.Object

Short answer: I have solved it by the following changes

```
ext.retrofit2Version = '2.4.0' -> '2.6.0'
implementation"com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit2Version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit2Version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit2Version"
```

Good luck

Answer (score 4):

in my case using this

```
compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
```

with this

```
new Retrofit.Builder().addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())...
```

solved the problem when nothing else worked

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using RxJava it properly makes no sense to add RxJava just for retrofit. `2.5.0` has support for `CompletableFuture` built in which you can use without adding any other library or adapter.

`build.gradle.kts`

```
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0")
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-converters:2.5.0")
```

`Api.kt`

```
interface Api {
    @GET("/resource")
    fun listCompanies(): CompletableFuture<ResourceDto>
}
```

Usage:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
   .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
   .baseUrl("https://api.example.com")
   .build()
   .create(Api::class.java)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to make the Call examples clearer for people who are migrating, not using Rx, or who want synchronous calls - Call essentially replaces (wraps) Response, meaning:

```
Response<MyObject> createRecord(...);
```

becomes

```
Call<MyObject> createRecord(...);
```

and not

```
Call<Response<MyObject>> createRecord(...);
```

(which will still require an adapter)

---

The Call will then allow you to still use `isSuccessful` as it actually returns a Response. So you can do something like:

```
myApi.createRecord(...).execute().isSuccessful()
```

Or access your Type (MyObject) like:

```
MyObject myObj = myApi.createRecord(...).execute().body();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface SimpleService {

  @GET("/simple/{id}")
  Simple getSimple(@Path("id") String id);

}
```

Communication with the network is done with the separate thread so you should change your Simple with that.

```
public interface SimpleService {

  @GET("/simple/{id}")
  Call<Simple> getSimple(@Path("id") String id);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used

```
com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.5.0 //notice rxjava
```

instead of

```
com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.5.0 //notice rxjava2
```

you should be using `com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.5.0` when using `io.reactivex.rxjava2`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a Callback, get the Simple from onResponse function.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Callback<Simple> {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Retrofit rest = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(endpoint)
                    .build();
        SimpleService service = rest.create(SimpleService.class);
        Call<Simple> call = service.getSimple("572642");
        //asynchronous call
        call.enqueue(this);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<Simple> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
       // response.body() has the return object(s)
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        // do something
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, in my situation is, I am using `ApiInterface.java` from JAVA to connect with the `MyViewModel.kt`which is from KOTLIN.

1. This is `ApiInterface.java`

   @GET(Constant.CONNECTION)
   Call<com.example.kt.model.ConnectionResponse> ConnectionKt();
2. You need to create a new Kotlin class, named as `ApiTemporary.kt`

   class ApiTemporary(
   private val apiInterface: ApiInterface =
   RetrofitClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiInterface::class.java)
   ) {

   suspend fun getConnectionKt(): Response {
   return apiInterface.ConnectionKt().awaitResponse()
   }
   }
3. So lastly, at `MyViewModel.kt`, you can do like this

val data = withContext(ioDispatcher) {
val result = apiTemporary.getConnectionKt()
if (result.isSuccessful) {
Resource.Success(result.body())
} else {
Resource.Error("Server error. Please try again")
}
}
_connection.value = data

So, the `ApiTemporary` will help to convert them from Java to Kotlin which is usage of Coroutines

Answer (score 0):

I solved by update retrofit version to 2.9.0 in gradle

Answer (score 0):

If your API interface is returning Response object then probably you forgot to add suspend function in your API interface.

**API Interface**

```
interface WeatherAPI {
    @GET("/data/2.5/weather")
    suspend fun getWeatherInfo(
        @Query("q") query: String
    ): Response<WeatherResponse>
}
```

**Repository**

```
class WeatherRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
private val weatherAPI: WeatherAPI
) : WeatherRepository {
    override suspend fun getWeatherInfo(query: String): Resource<WeatherResponse> {
        try {
            val response = weatherAPI.getWeatherInfo(query)
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                response.body()?.let {
                    return Resource.success(it)
                } ?: return Resource.error("Unknown error occurred", null)
            } else {
                return Resource.error("Unknown error occured", null)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return Resource.error("Please check your internet connection", null)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was working on the debug version but crashing in the release version. I fixed it by updating my `proguard-rules.pro` file with:

```
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
```

Answer (score -2):

The way I fixed this issue was adding this to the application gradle file, if the configuration is not set there will be conflicts, maybe this will be fixed in the stable release of the library:

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'stax'
    compile.exclude group: 'xpp3'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:2.0.0-beta1'
}
```

and create your adapter this way:

```
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(endPoint)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is exactly the same configuration as in my question. So, does not resolve anything :)