# Android Retrofit:On Response not calling

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using retrofit for the first time.I want to get the authentication returned from the Api but onResponse is not called. Here is my code:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://abc.def.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        ApiInterface service = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

        String setAPI_KEY = "123456";
        String settoken = "7891011";
        retrofit2.Call<TokenResponse> tokenResponseCall = service.getToken(setAPI_KEY, settoken);

        tokenResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<TokenResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<TokenResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<TokenResponse> response) {
                int a = response.code();
                TokenResponse tokenResponse = new TokenResponse();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<TokenResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.print("Fail");
            }
        });
```

In the Interface I am setting it like this:

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("/qwe/asd/zxc")
    Call<TokenResponse> getToken(@Query("key") String API_KEY,@Query("acesstoken") String token);

}
```

Any idea whats wrong in it? The complete URL is like this

https://abc.def.com/qwe/asd/zxc?key=Key&acesstoken=Token

Here is my TokenResponse Class:

```
public class TokenResponse {
    @SerializedName("authorization_key")
    private String authorization_key;

    public String getAuthorization_key() {
        return authorization_key;
    }
}
```

The Exception I am getting is : 
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: Is `onFailure` called?

Comment: Great, so give us the error you get

Comment: @TomaszCzura com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON

Comment: Please, edit you question by posting full stacktrace, response from endpoint and TokenResponse class

Comment: Done Editing @TomaszCzura

Comment: can u also add ur sample output?

Comment: @ArunShankar 7898fghjyiop596nflgml45667 this type of token will be returned

Comment: Ur webservice output is json or just token string?

Comment: @ArunShankar its token String

Comment: Could you post also your json response?

Comment: @TomaszCzura what do you mean by json response I could not get you this time?

Comment: Here Retrofit expecting TokenResponse output, but your response is String, So either you ask the one who done WebService to return json output, or follow this link to parse string response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617770/how-to-get-response-as-string-using-retrofit-without-using-gson-or-any-other-lib

Comment: Call your request by Postman or any other tool, even `curl` to see what endpoint really returns. Your problem is that response does not fit to Gson class, so we have to know what response is

Comment: Okay I am on it

Answer (score 0):

GSON throws that particular error when there's extra characters after the end of the object that aren't whitespace, and it defines whitespace very narrowly.

Use it

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setLenient()
    .create();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://abc.def.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
```

Comment: Returns : com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: Please share your json, Might be format is not valid.