# What's the same in Retrofit POST like StringRequest in Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit2

For example, I have Volley code for StringRequest here.

What do we use to achieve the same result for Retrofit and how does interface look like in this case?

```
        String url = getString(R.string.API_URL) + "/social/revoke-token";

        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest
                (Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {


                        Log.d("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", response.toString());


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO: Handle error

                    }
                 }){
```

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32621245/6672577

Comment: @Opriday And how to use Map for that? What changes would be required in Interface and Retrofit code?

Comment: Can you give me the link of your API so I can try it by myself then will post the code as an answer. I have searched to find the API which gives string response but could not find out.

Comment: Check this answer also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40973753/6672577

Comment: @Opriday I am creating logout function for facebook. I have to remove accesstoken from the server. So I have to pass fb token, client id, client secret to accomplish that.

https://gist.github.com/ashishkharcheiu/ff3203e33562d2fe4842ba9f62d2ffe3

Here is the gist of logout function.

http://157.230.83.171 this is the url with endpoint I am using is api/social/revoke-token

Comment: @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("url api url") // make sure you give base url to retrofit while makign retrofit object
Call<Result> logout(@Field("param1") int param1,@Field("param2") int param2); // mention all the parameter which you have puted in map. in retrofit you don't need to attach map so you have to pass those values as parameters to the function.

Comment: @Opriday also If I don't have model, should i use Call<String> or Call<ResponseBody> or something other?

Comment: If use ResponseBody then won't need model class for it.