# Why i am getting null if response in not success in response android retrofit API?

Tags: android, retrofit, jsonresponse

My problem is that when response is successful, i am getting response. But if response is not success, I am not getting any response in body, it's null. In case of any error like 404, 500 response is null. I am a beginner.

[image]

```
void sendMessage(){
    String user_id = sessionManager.getPreferences(getActivity(), "user_id");
    String message = binding.inputMessage.getText().toString();
    String api_key = "954f011a-ab85-42e";
    String secret_key = "v7FTQC&Cppbukk";
    if (message.isEmpty()){
        binding.inputMessage.setError("Please write your message");
        binding.inputMessage.requestFocus();
    }else {
        binding.inputMessage.setError(null);

        APIService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(APIService.class);
        Call<ContactUsModel> call = service.sendMessage(user_id, message, api_key, secret_key);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Sending");
        progressDialog.show();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ContactUsModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ContactUsModel> call, Response<ContactUsModel> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                ContactUsModel model = response.body();
                if (response.code() == 201){
                    if (model.getSuccess() == 1){
                        binding.inputMessage.setText("");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), model.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }else{
                   //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("responcebody" , response.body().toString());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ContactUsModel> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**My Model is below in which i am getting responce, parameters name are totally correct**

```
            package com.example.miinterest.model;
        
        import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
        
        public class ContactUsModel {
            @SerializedName("success") private int success;
            @SerializedName("message") private String message;
        
            public int getSuccess() {
                return success;
            }
        
            public void setSuccess(int success) {
                this.success = success;
            }
        
            public String getMessage() {
                return message;
            }
        
            public void setMessage(String message) {
                this.message = message;
            }
        }
```

**And Api Call Method. I created a method and calling API from here**

```
               @FormUrlEncoded
            @POST("addContactUsQuery")
            Call<ContactUsModel> sendMessage(
                    @Field("user_id") String user_id,
                    @Field("message") String message,
                    @Header("api_key") String api_key,
                    @Header("secret_key") String secret_key
            );
```

Comment: Actually, you don't get the null. Log the                    response.errorBody().toString(). You will get the output in case of 404,500

Comment: Please add the server response that your receive
also you need to check if the api call was successfully of not.
if (response.isSuccessful()) {} else { }

Comment: when i change response.body.toString to response.errorBody().toString(). Then i am getting   "okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@59bbee6" Error. I also included response.isSuccessfull().

Comment: @Rakesh saini convert the response to jsonObject and display it 
 put this 2 lines of codes inside try, catch block
 JSONObject jsonError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
 Log.e("error", jsonError.toString());

Comment: Thanks for reply, i applied your code but still getting null in "jsonError "

Comment: Please @Rakesh show me the log

Comment: I am getting following error -> i also updated screenshot in my question above please see the pic also -- >   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: @Rakesh response.isSuccessuful() returns true if code() is in the range [200..300)
 so please check the endpoint name is correct and if you web server intercept the 
 request and send response

Comment: Same API i am using in flutter but there its working fine, I also check your statement. But not solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is not `.toString()` but is `.string()`.
You should return your errorBody as `response.errorBody().string()`.
Please refer here

[How to get response as String using retrofit without using GSON or any other library in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617770/how-to-get-response-as-string-using-retrofit-without-using-gson-or-any-other-lib)