# Is it possible to parse json without creating CallAdapter in Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

I use retrofit2 in my project and I need to parse some json answer into custom object. So I created deserializer and called it in GsonBuilder

```
private final Gson _gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(DaysList.class, new DaysDeserializer())
    .create();
```

After that I defined Retrofit

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(_activity.getString(R.string.config_api_url))
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(_gson))
    .build();
```

But with defined retrofit service

```
Call<DaysList> retrofitHolidaysRequest()
```

I got an exception. After that I changed method signature to service method and it became:

```
DaysList retrofitHolidaysRequest()
```

Also I added to Retrofit.Builder my own CallAdapter.Factory and everything have worked as I need:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(_activity.getString(R.string.config_api_url))
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(_gson))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(new ResponseCallAdapterFactory())
    .build();
```

So the question is: Is it possible create own deserializers without defining own CallAdapters? If it is possible then what I did wrong?

Comment: So if you downvoted my question please explain why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like was mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269064/unable-to-create-call-adapter-for-class-example-simple) I need to use RxJavaCallAdapterFactory. It is not clear for me why, because I don't use RxJava, but it works well