# RxAndroid and Retrofit: Unable to create call adapter for io.reactivex.Observable<retrofit2.Response<okhttp3.ResponseBody>>

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am trying use rxJava, rxAndroid, Retrofit2, and OkHTTP3 to download a file from a URL endpoint. My code is unable to create the call adapter for an "Observable< retrofit2.Response< okhttp3.ResponseBody>>". These methods are new to me so I believe I'm missing an important concept here. Any direction or points is greatly appreciated.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.khe11e.rxdownloadfile, PID: 14130
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for io.reactivex.Observable>
>      for method RetrofitInterface.downloadFileByUrlRx
>      at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:720)
>      at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:234)
>      at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:160)
>      at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
>      at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
>      at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
>      at $Proxy0.downloadFileByUrlRx(Unknown Source)
>      at com.example.khe11e.rxdownloadfile.MainActivity.downloadImage(MainActivity.java:46)
>      at com.example.khe11e.rxdownloadfile.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)
>      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
>      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168)
>      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491)
>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for io.reactivex.Observable>.
>    Tried:
>     * retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory
>     * retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory
>      at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:237)
>      at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:201)
>      at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:232)
>       ... 16 more

build.gradle:

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
```

RetrofitInterface.java:

```
package com.example.khe11e.rxdownloadfile;
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Streaming;
import retrofit2.http.Url;

public interface RetrofitInterface {
    // Retrofit 2 GET request for rxjava
    @Streaming
    @GET
    Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> downloadFileByUrlRx(@Url String fileUrl);
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.khe11e.rxdownloadfile;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.File;
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.ObservableEmitter;
import io.reactivex.ObservableOnSubscribe;
import io.reactivex.Observer;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.functions.Function;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import okio.BufferedSink;
import okio.Okio;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button downloadImgBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    downloadImgBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downloadImgBtn);
    downloadImgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            downloadImage();
        }
    });
}

public void downloadImage(){
    RetrofitInterface downloadService = createService(RetrofitInterface.class, "https://www.nasa.gov/");
    downloadService.downloadFileByUrlRx("sites/default/files/iss_1.jpg")
            .flatMap(processResponse())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(handleResult());
}

public <T> T createService(Class<T> serviceClass, String baseUrl){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().build())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()).build();
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}

public Function<Response<ResponseBody>, Observable<File>> processResponse(){
    return new Function<Response<ResponseBody>, Observable<File>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<File> apply(Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) throws Exception {
            return saveToDiskRx(responseBodyResponse);
        }
    };
}

private Observable<File> saveToDiskRx(final Response<ResponseBody> response){
    return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<File>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<File> subscriber) throws Exception {
            String header = response.headers().get("Content-Disposition");
            String filename = header.replace("attachment; filename=", "");
            new File("/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/images").mkdir();
            File destinationFile = new File("/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/images/" + filename);

            BufferedSink bufferedSink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(destinationFile));
            bufferedSink.writeAll(response.body().source());
            bufferedSink.close();

            subscriber.onNext(destinationFile);
            subscriber.onComplete();
        }
    });
}

private Observer<File> handleResult(){
    return new Observer<File>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            Log.d("OnSubscribe", "OnSubscribe");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(File file) {
            Log.d("OnNext", "File downloaded to " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Error", "Error " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.d("OnComplete", "onCompleted");
        }
    };
}
}
```

I've tried adding Call as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269064/unable-to-create-call-adapter-for-class-example-simple) so it looks like:

```
Call<Observable<Response<ResponseBody>>> downloadFileByUrlRx(@Url String fileUrl);
```

however this causes issues with the flatMap function as it cannot find symbol method flatMap(Function< Response< ResponseBody>,Observable< File>>).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You are using RxJava**1** adapter for Retrofit, replace it with RxJava**2** variant:

```
//compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
```

**UPDATE**

Starting with Retrofit version `2.2.0` there is a first-party call adapter for RxJava2:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
```

Answer (score 47):

## Update : May/2020

New adapter for RxJava 3

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava3:2.9.0'
```

`RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create()` instead of `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()`

---

## Update : June/2019

Rxjava version is updated to 2.2.10

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.10'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0'
```

Also Retrofit requires at minimum Java 7 or Android 2.3

```
------------------------------------------
```

## For new comers (July/2017) :

You messed your library version for sure.

I have been using latest version of RXAndroid 2.0.1

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
```

1) Make sure you have same Retrofit and Retrofit-RxJava Adapters.

2) Use compile

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
```

not

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
```

and use **`RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()`** instead of `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()` while building retrofit.

Comment: and use `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()` instead of `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()` while building retrofit.

Comment: Thank you for your note. i updated the answer with it.

Comment: And Also use **io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers** instead of **rx.schedulers.Schedulers**

Comment: How come the **May/2020** update for the `rxjava3-retrofit-adapter` comes from `akarnokd` rather than the `io.reactivex` project similar to the previous Retrofit adapter releases?

Comment: It looks like it might be merged into `io.reactivex` at some point in the future.

Comment: The adapter has been [merged](https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/3315#issuecomment-631559235) today into `com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava3:2.9.0`.

Comment: Crash. Unable to create adapter with `RxJava3CallAdapterFactory`

Comment: Thanks man, took me much time to figure `rxjava3:2.9.0`

Comment: It seems to be working now! Thank you. I just synced all the updated dependencies.

Answer (score -5):

Since you use response header, so replace `ResponseBody` to `Object` everywhere.